# Rotation animation dosn't work properly

Tags: animation

I wanted to make Rubik's Cube animation but something gone wrong.

At the beginning all working properly, sides rotates like i want. But at some point Rubik's Cube start to breaking down.

### [image: Broken Rubik's Cube]

What i did: Rotate side > A > I (Rotation) > Rotate another side > A > I (Rotation) > etc

I tried to solve it, but my knowlegde is insufitient at the moment.

My version is 2.81

Project files:
http://www.filedropper.com/rubikscube